# Using ajax to retrieve a data grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

This is my first time trying to use ajax.  I am successful in retrieving data from a table, but I want to be able to pull in a whole data grid.  I am not entirely sure how to go about doing this.

Right now, I have my index.php file looking like this:

```
 <html>
 <head><title>Ajax Stuff</title>
 </head>
 <body>
   <input id="username" name="username" type="text" />
   <button type="submit" id="myBtn" name="myBtn">Submit</button>

   <div id="name-data"></div> // <-data will be sent here

   <script src="js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
   <script src="js/global.js"></script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Here is the code for global.js:

```
 $('#myBtn').on('click', function(){
   var name = $('#username').val();
   if($.trim(name) != '')
   {
     $.post('ajax/name.php', {username: name}, function(data){
       $('#name-data').text(data);
     });
   }
 });
```

And finally, here is the code for the ajax file called name.php:

```
 <?php
   include("../include/database/php");

   if(isset($_POST['username']) === true && empty($_POST['username']) === false)
   {
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '" . mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['username'])) . "'");
    $resnum = mysql_num_rows($query);

    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

    // I just added these next few line 

    echo "username: "  . $row[username] . " ";
    echo "full name: " . $row[fullname] . " ";
    echo "emaill: " . $row[email] . " ";
    echo "user level: " . $row[userlevel] . " ";
    echo "division: " . $row[division] . " ";
    echo "phone: " . $row[phone] . " ";
    echo "created by: " . $row[created_by] . " ";

 }
```

Using the above PHP code, I can display the rows I requested.  But I tried to add a table (in name.php), my main file, index.php actually shows the code for the table on the screen.

Any time I try to use HTML code in the PHP file, it prints the HTML code to the screen.

For instance, I try to use a BR tag like this:

```
 <?php
   echo "username: "  . $row[username] . "<br />";
 ?>
```

The screen will print this:

```
 username: johbea1234 <br />
```

The same thing when I try to use table tags.

How can I fix this?

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
$('#name-data').text(data);
```

to

```
$('#name-data').html(data);
```

Then you can use any HTML tags you like.

Also

```
<div id="name-data"></div> // <-data will be sent here
```

isn't quite true, it's more like:

```
<div id="name-data"><!-- data will be sent here --></div>
```

but you might have known that already and just added the comment for those who might be reading your question.

Comment: Regarding the div, I was trying to put a comment in stack overflow. Other than that, I will attempt what you are asking.  I will get back to you.

Comment: I just tested it.  That worked.  Thanks, dude.  Upvote to you.

Answer (score 0):

Add `''` for `username`.

Change

```
$.post('ajax/name.php', {username: name}, function(data){.....
```

to

```
$.post('ajax/name.php', {'username': name}, function(data){.....
```